# How do I delete all related files in file folder and the references in my database at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

My application has supporting models that refer to their corresponding SQL tables. One `SBanInfos` has all the data about the user. The other, `SBanFileDetails` has all of stores a guid of the the file matching the guid, and the source of the file itself.

In edit mode I can delete the files individually from the file folder and from `SBanFileDetails` simultaneously like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteFile(string id)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { Result = "Error" });
    }
    try
    {
        Guid guid = new Guid(id);
        SBanFileDetail sBanFileDetail = db.SBanFileDetails.Find(guid);
        if (sBanFileDetail == null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            return Json(new { Result = "Error" });
        }

        //Remove from database
        db.SBanFileDetails.Remove(sBanFileDetail);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Delete file from the file system
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/pathto/myfile/"), sBanFileDetail.Id + sBanFileDetail.Extension);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
        return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

And I know from experience that I can remove all of the `SBanFileDetails` related to the user and the user record like so:

```
SBanInfo sBanInfo = db.SBanInfos.Find(id);
    db.SBanFileDetails
       .Where(p => p.SubjectId == id)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(p => db.SBanFileDetails.Remove(p));
    db.SBanInfos.Remove(sBanInfo);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

My question is, how do I remove the references from the database and the files from the folder at the same time?

Comment: Do "select" first, delete all files retrieved from the DB, and then delete the refs in the DB. You have all puzzle pieces in place already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrei suggested I placed all of the pieces above in the correct order to resolve the issue. Final code looks like this

```
var subjectIdResult = (from sId in db.SBanInfos where sId.SubjectId == id select sId.SubjectId).Single();
var fileDetailsResult = (from fd in db.SBanFileDetails where fd.SubjectId == subjectIdResult select fd.Id).ToList();

foreach(var fileId in fileDetailsResult)
{ 
    Guid guid = new Guid(fileId.ToByteArray());
    SBanFileDetail sBanFileDetail = db.SBanFileDetails.Find(guid);

    //Delete files from the file system
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/pathto/myfiles/"), sBanFileDetail.Id + sBanFileDetail.Extension);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
    }
}

SBanInfo sBanInfo = db.SBanInfos.Find(id);
db.SBanFileDetails
   .Where(p => p.SubjectId == id)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(p => db.SBanFileDetails.Remove(p));
db.SBanInfos.Remove(sBanInfo);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```